# MPI_Init() taking a very long time to run

Tags: windows-8, cygwin, fortran, mpi, fortran90

I have a minimal example of a problem where I am simply starting up 4 processes (on a quad core Intel Core i7 cpu with 8 threads) and for some reason `MPI_Init` seems to take a very, very long time.

Here is my code:

```
 1 program smear_sfs
 2
 3 integer, parameter :: ikind = 4
 4 integer, parameter :: rkind = 8
 5
 6 integer(kind = ikind) :: isize, iproc, ierr
 7 integer(kind = ikind) :: i, j
 8
 9 include "mpif.h"
10 integer(kind = ikind) :: istat(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
11
12 print*, 'Section 1'
13
14 ! initialize mpi
15 write(*, '(a)', advance='no'), 'Calling MPI_Init ...'
16 call MPI_Init(ierr)
17 write(*, '(a)') 'done'
18 print*, 'ierr = ', ierr
19 call MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
20 call MPI_Comm_Rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, iproc, ierr)
21 call MPI_Comm_Size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, isize, ierr)
22 do i = 0,isize
23   call MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
24   if(iproc.eq.i) write(*, '(a, i3, a)') 'rank(', iproc, ') reporting'
25   call MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
26 enddo
27
28 ! shutdown MPI
29 call MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
30 call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
31
32 end program smear_sfs
```

and here is a (timed) version of the output:

```
 Section 1
Calling MPI_Init ... Section 1
Calling MPI_Init ... Section 1
Calling MPI_Init ... Section 1
Calling MPI_Init ...done
 ierr =            0
rank(  0) reporting
done
 ierr =            0
rank(  1) reporting
done
 ierr =            0
rank(  2) reporting
done
 ierr =            0
rank(  3) reporting

real    0m45.350s
user    1m25.794s
sys     1m31.731s
```

The program outputs `Section 1` and the following `Calling MPI_Init ...`'s right away but then hangs for a long time afterwards before printing `done` and the rest of the output. For some reason, this is hanging for a long time on `MPI_Init` and I can't figure out why.

If it matters at all, the first time I ran this I got some sort of strange warning from my firewall claiming that something was happening to my computer (from `orted.exe` I think it was) but I have not gotten that error anymore.

I am running this on Windows 8 through cygwin64 and compiling with MPIf90.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of what I assume to be Open MPI are you using?

Comment: I am using OpenMPI 1.7.1

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu Linux, I get (real, user, sys) values of (1.054s, 0.048s, 0.024s).

Comment: I figured this was not a problem with the code itself since I have written MPI on other platforms before. Does anyone know how cygwin or Windows 8 might play into the way that MPI is used?

Comment: What happens if you turn off your firewall (temporarily)?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully the last edit:

I asked in the OpenMPI user mailing list. There I got the advice, that it also could be my WLAN.

And indeed! It was my WLAN, at least half the time I tested it. The other time it was my LAN, which I also use to access the internet.

So: Try to deactivate LAN and WLAN in Start > Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center > Change Adapter Settings
This is only a workaround, though.

---

This is not a real answer, but I want to share my 5 hours experience with this vexing subject. (I still have the problem from time to time)

I had the same problem: after compiling and running a program, it seems to hang, but it eventually will work after a minute or two.

While the problem occured on my Notebook it did not on my desktop PC. Both run on Win 7, cygwin 64 Bit, OpenMPI version 1.8.3 r32794 (ompi_info), g++ v 4.8.3. I actually synced the cygwin installations later on, and it still didn't work, but it did after a restart, so I can't really exclude that the problem was a somehow botched up cygwin installation.

When I started a program on my desktop PC my Firewall Comodo 5.10 notified me about orterun.exe (mpirun is only a symlink to orterun) and myprogram.exe. After I (permanently) allowed these two programs the started program still didn't resume execution. After canceling the program and restarting it, the program ran without problems, meaning it ran fast. Because of this, it seems to me that OpenMPI maybe has only insufficient error-handling if it can't connect instantly. Maybe this is somehow related to the problem.

I'm using Comodo Firewall 5.10. on my Desktop and absolutely no Firewall, not even the Windows Firewall (deactivated) on my Notebook. Installing Comodo 5.10 on my notebook didn't help either. But everything worked after restarting, so maybe the Firewall wasn't completely in place yet? But the Installation program didn't prompt me to restart and the Firewall was already working, so ...

A compiled version from my desktop PC did run on my notebook with mpirun... I think. Alas I couldn't replicate this and I tried for hours now. Because of this I thought the error lay in the compiler or OpenMPI-libraries.

After syncing my cygwin installation on my notebook with the one on my desktop, installing a firewall where I allowed all affected programs and restarting my notebook it finally worked... I am not sure what exactly solved the problem and why a restart was necessary.

Obviously the problem existed quite some months on my notebook, so I DID restart the notebook before without the problem being solved.

Other people also have stories of their VPN software interfering with OpenMPI and causing exactly these problems, but I didn't have such a software running.

Edit:
Some hours later the problem is back!
Things that I also fruitlessly tried:

- closing programs which could jam TCP-IP connections
- ping 127.0.0.1 works <1ms
- running bash as administrator
- running orterun/mpirun from windows cmd instead of cygwin-bash
- stopping Windows Firewall Service and Windows Defender completely
- using MPI_Init(NULL,NULL); instead of MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
- compiling with gcc instead of g++
- the program works fine, if I don't start it with mpirun, but it also doesn't work, if I start it with mpirun -n 1
- update Windows
- using safe mode (with network drivers)
- trying to debug it (I can't get a useful backtrace to the MPI_init call)

Comment: You should post this as a new question and also ask on the [Open MPI User mailing list](http://www.open-mpi.org/community/lists/ompi.php). There are many MCA parameters for enabling verbose mode in the various Open MPI frameworks and those could be used for debugging such issues.